# Writing an iterator that wraps starts towards the end and wraps around to print all elements in order

Tags: java, arrays, iterator

I need to write an Iterator for a wrap around array in which the front of the list starts towards the end. So the Iterator needs to start at the "front" variable, iterate until the end of the list, and then start at the beginning of the list and iterate until it hits "rear".

the last element in the array "rear" is not being printed and when the array is full it does not print any of the elements.

```
public Iterator<E> iterator(){      
    return new IteratorAssist();
}

class IteratorAssist implements Iterator<E> {

    public IteratorAssist() {
        index = front;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {

        if(index != data.length)
            return index != rear + 1 ;
        else if(index == data.length)
            index = 0;
        return index != rear + 1;
    }
    @Override
    public E next() {
        if(!hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        return data[index++];
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as solutions, I would simply concatenate `data` with itself then iterate over the result, thus avoiding hassles with pointers.

Comment: can you show the code where you set front and rear? Do they change at any point, and are you sure they are not the same element and that front is always > rear? Also, the code with the two printout cases (where the rear element is skipped, and when all elements are skipped) will be very useful.

Comment: I wrote an answer below that could be useful for your issue. If you could add a little more details to your question, I'll be happy to add to it and make it more specific. If you feel it helped you, would you consider accepting it? It's just clicking the gray check mark next to the answer, making it green?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from the code you posted so far, but your issue with full array not being printed may be connected to `index=front` in the constructor of the iterator, and the possibility that `front=rear+1` (when the array is completely full). so when you start from front you get immediate false on `hasNext()` and you cannot iterate.

If this is the case, you can fix it by always keeping a gap cell between front and rear on wrap-back. I could help you recommend a way to do this if you post the code of the class you're iterating.